# Thumbnailctrl size (trying to get it to fullscreen)

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, thumbnails, splitter

I've been trying to insert two Thubmnailctrl under a Multisplitter, I have managed to put them in there, but I can't manage to make them ocuppy the full space. On thumbnailctrl.py I've seen that on the the maximum size it can be is 350x280:

```
def SetThumbSize(self, width, height, border=6):
"""
Sets the thumbnail size as width, height and border.

:param `width`: the desired thumbnail width;
:param `height`: the desired thumbnail height;
:param `border`: the spacing between thumbnails.
"""

if width > 350 or height > 280:
    return

self._tWidth = width 
self._tHeight = height
self._tBorder = border
self.SetScrollRate((self._tWidth + self._tBorder)/4,
                   (self._tHeight + self._tBorder)/4)
self.SetSizeHints(self._tWidth + self._tBorder*2 + 16,
                  self._tHeight + self._tBorder*2 + 8)
```

But on the other hand on the demo under ThumbnailCtrl, it uses an Splitter to create a Thumbnailctrl as big as you want, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (maybe with Sizers) or is some feature from Splitter (totally diferent than multisplitter) that allows the Thumbnailctrl to occupy it's full space.

Thumbnailctrl + Splitter Demo:

```
import wx
import os
import sys

try:
    dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except:
    dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

sys.path.append(os.path.split(dirName)[0])

try:
    from agw import thumbnailctrl as TC
except ImportError:  # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
import wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl as TC


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Elephant")

    # self.SetMenuBar(self.CreateMenuBar())

    splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1, style=wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.SP_3D | wx.WANTS_CHARS | wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
    self.panel = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    scroll = TC.ThumbnailCtrl(splitter, -1, imagehandler=TC.NativeImageHandler)

    scroll.ShowFileNames()
    if os.path.isdir("../bitmaps"):
        scroll.ShowDir(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + "/../bitmaps"))
    else:
        scroll.ShowDir(os.getcwd())

    self.TC = scroll

    splitter.SplitVertically(scroll, self.panel, 180)

    splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(140)
    self.SetMinSize((700, 590))
    self.CenterOnScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    # import wx.lib.inspection
    # wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

My attempt at a Multisplitter with two thumbnails (and when that works a third panel with text and stuff):

```
import wx
import os
import cv2
import ctypes
from PIL import Image
from wx.lib.splitter import MultiSplitterWindow

try:
    from agw import thumbnailctrl as TC
except ImportError:  # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    import wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl as TC


class SamplePane(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.thumbnail11 = TC.ThumbnailCtrl(self, imagehandler=TC.NativeImageHandler, thumboutline=4)
    self.thumbnail11.EnableDragging(True)
    # self.thumbnail11.SetThumbSize(350, screensize[0] / 15, 25)  # For images -> Max values 350,280

    # ################VID################ #

    topmostSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    topmostSizer.Add(self.thumbnail11, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(topmostSizer)
    self.MaxSize
    # topmostSizer.Fit(self)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
""""""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Elephant")

        splitter = MultiSplitterWindow(self, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)
        # t1Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # self.thumbnail11 = TC.ThumbnailCtrl(splitter, imagehandler=TC.NativeImageHandler, thumboutline=4)
        panel = SamplePane(splitter)
        splitter.AppendWindow(panel)
        panel2 = SamplePane(splitter)
        splitter.AppendWindow(panel2)
        # t1Sizer.Add(panel, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)

    frame = MainFrame()
    # import wx.lib.inspection
    # wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see there are two thumbnails and they expand left to right, but they are capped at a maximum height.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what it is that you're trying achieve with this but I suspect that your problem is with the `topmostSizer`'s `proportion` attribute.
Try:

```
topmostSizer.Add(self.thumbnail11, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

From the manual:

> proportion - Although the meaning of this parameter is undefined in
>   wx.Sizer, it is used in wx.BoxSizer to indicate if a child of a sizer
>   can change its size in the main orientation of the wx.BoxSizer - where
>   0 stands for not changeable and a value of more than zero is
>   interpreted relative (a proportion of the total) to the value of other
>   children of the same wx.BoxSizer.

In this case, you have defined `topmostSizer` as VERTICAL